# Compute task with query from cache

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I'm new to Apache Ignite (using 2.7) and I'm looking to create a set of compute tasks that also query data from a cache.  I see in the docs the concept of collocated processing but I don't see any examples in the repo.  Couple of things I'm unclear on:

1) I want to query the cache from within the task, do I need to create another instance of Cache using Ignite.start or Client mode from within this task, or is there some implicit variable I can use from the context to query the cache.

2) Specifically I'd like to to execute this task as the result of a Continuous Query callback, are there any example detailing that?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. You should [inject an instance of Ignite](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/resource-injection) into your task - this is preferred approach.
2. This may be tricky - make sure to not run this task synchronously since you should not acquire any locks from Continuous Query callback. Maybe Async() methods are OK. The preferred approach is to schedule a taks into your own thread pool to handle procesing latter, and return from callback. Make sure that you don't wait on thread pool as it exhausts (since the common strategy is to run task synchronously if pool is full).